# Pulseaudio fail to start at boot

Tags: pulseaudio, systemd

When I boot PA does not start. Syslog show this:

```
$ grep 'pulseaudio' /var/log/syslog

Mar 26 08:08:30 MX systemd[1171]: /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service:16: Failed to add dependency on pulseaudio, ignoring: Invalid argument
Mar 26 08:08:30 MX systemd[1331]: /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service:16: Failed to add dependency on pulseaudio, ignoring: Invalid argument
Mar 26 08:08:31 MX systemd[1331]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed to queue service startup job (Maybe the service file is missing or not a non-template unit?): Unit -d.socket not found.
Mar 26 08:08:31 MX systemd[1331]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
Mar 26 08:08:41 MX systemd[1788]: /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service:16: Failed to add dependency on pulseaudio, ignoring: Invalid argument
Mar 26 08:08:42 MX systemd[1788]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed to queue service startup job (Maybe the service file is missing or not a non-template unit?): Unit -d.socket not found.
Mar 26 08:08:42 MX systemd[1788]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
Mar 26 08:08:43 MX pulseaudio.desktop[2060]: Connection failure: Connection refused
Mar 26 08:08:43 MX pulseaudio.desktop[2060]: pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
Mar 26 08:08:43 MX gnome-session[1820]: gnome-session-binary[1820]: WARNING: App 'pulseaudio.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 26 08:08:43 MX gnome-session-binary[1820]: WARNING: App 'pulseaudio.desktop' exited with code 1
```

When I log in, the service is not running and nothing is under Sound in Settings.

However. Starting PA manually after I have logged in works fine:

```
$ pulseaudio --start
```

And no additional errors are logged in syslog.

---

Looks like there might be some *"Invalid argument"* somewhere. How to find? Or is there an easy way to reset PA back to defaults?

As it is system default audio I am a bit hesitant to uninstall it (for then to reinstall) if something should be lost, or things become even worse. Have experienced that before.